# Pipeline.py to drop Value rather than Field

Tags: python, error-handling, exception, scrapy

I'm currently working on a Scrapy script to pull product information from an Amazon page. The problem I'm running in to is exception handling that drops only the erroneous field rather than the entire item/row in my output.

Current Spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from dirbot.items import Website


class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004YVOU9S",
        "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B009NFE2QQ"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "a-container")]')
        items = []

            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['asin'] = response.url.split('/')[-1]
                item['title'] = site.xpath('div[@id="centerCol"]/div[@id="title_feature_div"]/div[@id="titleSection"]/h1[@id="title"]/span[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract()
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="productDescription"]/div/div[1]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
                item['price'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()').extract()
                item['image'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="landingImage"]/@data-a-dynamic-image').extract()
                item['brand'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="brand"]/text()').extract()
                item['bullets'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="feature-bullets"]/span/ul').extract()[0].strip()
                item['category'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="wayfinding-breadcrumbs_feature_div"]/ul').extract()[0].strip()
                item['details'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="prodDetails"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table').extract()[0].strip()
                items.append(item)

            return items
```

When an scrape result is missing any of the fields, I currently get the error:

```
exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range
```

To combat this, I added some exception handling in the form of an IgnoreRequest.

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

from dirbot.items import Website


class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004YVOU9S",
        "http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B009NFE2QQ"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "a-container")]')
        items = []

        try:
            for site in sites:
                item = Website()
                item['asin'] = response.url.split('/')[-1]
                item['title'] = site.xpath('div[@id="centerCol"]/div[@id="title_feature_div"]/div[@id="titleSection"]/h1[@id="title"]/span[@id="productTitle"]/text()').extract()
                item['description'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="productDescription"]/div/div[1]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
                item['price'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()').extract()
                item['image'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="landingImage"]/@data-a-dynamic-image').extract()
                item['brand'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="brand"]/text()').extract()
                item['bullets'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="feature-bullets"]/span/ul').extract()[0].strip()
                item['category'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="wayfinding-breadcrumbs_feature_div"]/ul').extract()[0].strip()
                item['details'] = site.xpath('//*[@id="prodDetails"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table').extract()[0].strip()
                items.append(item)

            return items

        except IndexError:
                raise IgnoreRequest("Data type not found.")
```

What I'd like to do is handle this error in a way that continues to output the rest of the spiders results, dropping only the field with no value, rather than ignoring the entire item.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do different solutions, If you want to go with try , catch and delete only single field, then you have to do this for all fields,

```
    try:
        //extract field
    except IndexError:
        raise IgnoreRequest("Data type not found.")
```

If you want an empty value instead of dropping then you have to check if value exist or not, you can define a seperate method for extraction

```
    def get_value_from_node(self, node):
        value = node.extract()
        return value[0] if value else ''
```

and call this method for all fields

```
    item['title'] = self.get_value_from_node(site.xpath('div[@id="centerCol"]/div[@id="title_feature_div"]/div[@id="titleSection"]/h1[@id="title"]/span[@id="productTitle"]/text()'))
```

it will return either value or an empty string. and no need of exception handling.

Comment: It looks like this is allowing me to raise individual ignore requests against my list of items, but the entire row is still dropped as a result.

I've just tried a few different runs, but each time it has automatically skipped to item['bullets'], raised the exception and stopped.

Comment: do you want any empty value instead ?

Comment: Yeah, my intended result would be:

asin, title, image
123, 123, 123
123, , 123

Rather than skipping out the entire second row, it simply skips the missing value.

Comment: @SamClarke I have updated answer, it will return value if xpath is valid and value is present on the website, otherwise it will return ''

Comment: @SamClarke FYI, this is reinventing the wheel. Item loaders + processors is the Scrapy-way to do what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

[`Item Loaders`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) with an *input or output processors* are what you need here.

Define an `ItemLoader` with a [`TakeFirst` processor](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.processor.TakeFirst):

> Returns the first non-null/non-empty value from the values received,
>   so it’s typically used as an output processor to single-valued fields.
>   It doesn’t receive any constructor arguments, nor accept Loader
>   contexts.

```
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst

class ProductLoader(ItemLoader):

    default_output_processor = TakeFirst()

    # specific field loaders
```

Then, load the item with the loader:

```
for site in sites:
    l = ProductLoader(Website(), site)
    l.add_value('asin', response.url.split('/')[-1]) # (4)
    l.add_xpath('title', 'div[@id="centerCol"]/div[@id="title_feature_div"]/div[@id="titleSection"]/h1[@id="title"]/span[@id="productTitle"]/text()')
    # ...

    yield l.load_item()
```